# Call to undefined method ConnectionManager::getInstance() cakephp ugrade 1.3 to 2.0

Tags: cakephp, upgrade

I am getting the **error**:

> Error: Call to undefined method ConnectionManager::getInstance() File:
>   /app/Controller/UsersController.php Line: 11

below are the function:

```
function changeDbSource($database = 'default') {   

    $db = ConnectionManager::getInstance();

    $connected = $db->getDataSource($database);

    if ($connected->isConnected()) {

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }
}
```

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it to

```
function changeDbSource($database = 'default') {
    $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource($database);
    return $db->isConnected();
}
```

`getDataSource` is now a static method